# How to call controller post method with custom spring boot login form

Tags: spring-security

I am new in Spring Security. I have simple mvc application and problem occurs when I want to call controller's post method which request mapping value is the same as a loginProcessingUrl's value.

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showlogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLogin() {
        System.out.println("Showing login...");
        return "login";
    }

    // this method is not being invoked
    @RequestMapping(value = "/authuser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void printUserData() {
        System.out.println("Printing user data...");
    }
}
```

Config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        User.UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
              .withUser(users.username("dejan").password("dejan").roles("EMPLOYEE"))
                .withUser(users.username("marko").password("marko").roles("ADMINISTRATOR"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/showlogin")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authuser")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Custom login page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form th:action="@{/authuser}" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you post a question and get answers, take a while to tell us if one answer solve your problem. This can help other users. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is here:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            ...

}
```

Change this to:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/showlogin")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authuser")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property  named `continueChainBeforeSuccessfulAuthentication` in the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` can do that. But seems it does not expose any configuration about that,

So you need to create `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` by yourself in stead of the `formLogin`, and set `continueChainBeforeSuccessfulAuthentication` to `true`